# MoneyWorks: Programmatically update a record

Tags: php, api, rest

I wanted to update a record in MoneyWorks. I can create using REST Api but I didn't find a help to update a record.

I'm using this documentation http://cognito.co.nz/developer/moneyworks-datacentre-rest-api/

To create a record im using following code and it is working

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://server/REST/username:password@doc/import/table=name&format=xml-verbose");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

where $xml is the input xml in string. In the documentation they have mentioned that we can update the record, but they didn't provide an example.

please help me to update a record using REST Api

Comment: To update a record you should follow the same procedure, supplying a record with an **existing** id.

Comment: can u pls give me an example... there is no ID tag in the xml... so how to supplying the id ?

Comment: `CODE`, not `ID`. The unique identifier there seems to be `CODE`.

Comment: i have already tried it... but i got this error... Line 22: The code 3 is already in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't specify the table name and format in the URL (you would use those for an export, which is a `GET`).
The table name and other import parameters are specified as attributes of the table element in the xml. To update records, specify `update="true"`. See the documentation here http://cognito.co.nz/developer/xml-data-exchange/

For example, you can import the following xml to update one field of the name record for SPRING. You can test this out by copying the xml and just pasting it into any list window in MoneyWorks (that invokes an XML import in MoneyWorks Gold 7.1.8 and later). The same XML will work for a REST import.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table name="Name" update="true">
    <name>
        <code>SPRING</code>
        <contact>New contact name</contact>
    </name>
</table>
```